# Index not used when querying 2 columns in 2 different tables OR condition

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

I am trying to get the query below to be indexed. If I use an OR condition with 2 joined tables it will NOT be indexed no mater the order of join or if I use straight join. If I only pick one of the columns the query is indexed.

NO INDEX:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `phppos_customers` 
JOIN `phppos_people` ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id` 
WHERE (`first_name`= 'TEST' or account_number='TEST')

+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys            | key       | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_people    | ALL  | PRIMARY,first_name       | NULL      | NULL    | NULL                        | 3526 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_customers | ref  | account_number,person_id | person_id | 4       | pos.phppos_people.person_id |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

INDEXED:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `phppos_customers` 
JOIN `phppos_people` ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id` 
WHERE (`first_name`= 'TEST')

+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_people    | ref  | PRIMARY,first_name | first_name | 767     | const                       |    1 | Using index condition |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_customers | ref  | person_id          | person_id  | 4       | pos.phppos_people.person_id |    1 | NULL                  |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------------------+
```

TABLES:

```
| phppos_people | CREATE TABLE `phppos_people` (
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comments` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
  KEY `phppos_people_ibfk_1` (`image_id`),
  KEY `first_name` (`first_name`),
  KEY `last_name` (`last_name`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `phone_number` (`phone_number`),
  KEY `full_name` (`full_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_app_files` (`file_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3510 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


| phppos_customers | CREATE TABLE `phppos_customers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `override_default_tax` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `credit_limit` decimal(23,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `disable_loyalty` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `current_spend_for_points` decimal(23,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000000',
  `current_sales_for_discount` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxable` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `tax_certificate` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cc_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc_ref_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc_preview` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `card_issuer` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `tier_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_number` (`account_number`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `cc_token` (`cc_token`),
  KEY `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` (`tier_id`),
  KEY `company_name` (`company_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_people` (`person_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tier_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_price_tiers` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3508 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 2):

When MySQL have in WHERE condition OR between different tables. like in Your case:

```
SELECT * FROM `phppos_customers` 
JOIN `phppos_people` ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id` 
WHERE (phppos_people.`first_name`= 'TEST' or phppos_customers.account_number='TEST')
```

it work slower than UNION ALL of 2 queries

what happens - native index for this construction is absent, so server need intersect 2 index (You can read - spend additional time and resources)

when You use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE first_name = 'TEST'

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE account_number='TEST'
```

in each subquery work only single index,

Difference for each time, will depend from many other parameters, but on some live processes this operation give me up to 100 times better performance. In Our case it was reduce time from 0.3 to 0.01 sec and on series from 200 000 queries per day it reduce loading dramatically.

Also good idea - stop use * for column list

Answer (score 1):

In general it is tricky to utilize indexes for disjunktions (OR). Assume you have an index where the first column is `first_name`. By using this index you basically skip rows that still may qualify due to the predicate `account_number = 'TEST'.

Some DBMS can do INDEX ORING, but I don't think MySQL can do that.

You can try to rewrite the query with a `UNION ALL` and see if that helps:

```
SELECT * FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE first_name = 'TEST'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE account_number='TEST'
```

Note that this query is not exactly equivalent with your query since it can result in duplicate rows. If it did help you can try replacing UNION ALL with UNION.

Somehow, I doubt that the above helps. You may want to execute two queries and do the union in the application:

```
SELECT * FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE first_name = 'TEST';
```

Store result in a set in application, and then execute next query:

```
SELECT * FROM phppos_customers 
JOIN phppos_people 
    ON phppos_customers.person_id = phppos_people.person_id 
WHERE account_number='TEST'
```

Add these rows to the same set